# Sending text to label printer not working at all

Tags: vb.net

On beginning i would like to highligth that i've tried a lot of things to make it done but without success and i am really stack and hoping i find some help here. My client has some 'sato' label printer which is placed on some ip address and on port 9100 some specific text data in predefined format has to be sent to print it. I was trying couple of diffrent code without success (below) - from what i know it should be fine. I am not getting any errors or whatever it looks like data is sending correctly but printer doesn't want to print. I check using some external tools like hyper terminal to check if at all printer working or not - it does and was able to send the file on this ip/port and printer starts to print. What could be wrong with what i am doing? Below find my diffrent code tries.

```
    Public Sub WriteData(ByVal data As String, ByRef IP As String)
try
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message """ & data & """ to " & IP)
        Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient()
        client.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), My.Settings.CommPort))
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
   Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.toString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

also tried this:

```
     ' Printer IP Address and communication port
        Dim ipAddress As String = "192.168.1.21"
        Dim port As Integer = 9100

        ' ZPL Command(s)
        Dim ZPLString As String = ""

        Try
            ' Open connection
            Using client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
                client.Connect(ipAddress, port)

                ' Write ZPL String to connection
                Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream())
                    writer.Write(ZPLString)
                    writer.Flush()
                End Using
            End Using
                ' Catch Exception
        Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.toString)
        End Try
```

and also this:

```
Try
     Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.21");
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
        clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");

        clientSocket.Send(fileBytes);
        clientSocket.Close();
   Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.toString)
        End Try
```

and this:

```
Try
     Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        clientSocket.NoDelay = True

        Dim ip As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.21")
        Dim ipep As New IPEndPoint(ip, 9100)
        clientSocket.Connect(ipep)

        Dim fileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt")

        clientSocket.Send(fileBytes)
        clientSocket.Close()
   Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.toString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Do you have any model name/number and/or documentation related to your label printer? And can you tell us what external apps you used and how you got them to work?

Comment: Perhaps your label printer requires a file and not just a plain string?

Comment: i have files - if i am sending particural file by external app e.g Hyper Terminal it works, when i send same file by code i shown in main topic it's not.

Comment: Well that doesn't tell me anything that you haven't already covered in your post.

Comment: If it takes a file, `File.ReadAllBytes()` should do.

Comment: also I see that you have "catch ex as exception" but you are not doing anything with the ex -- you should include msgbox(ex.tostring) so if the application is breaking in that portion, you will know

Comment: @JohnDoe please show to me _how_ you send the file via **Hyper Terminal**.

Comment: @Visual Vincent Hes opening hyper terminal putting new connection  - defining ip of printer, port and then selecting send the file and picking up the file. Printer name is "Sato" - i will take exact name from client and let you know.

Comment: @Nefariis - for all of them i use catch and msgbox to show if there would be error - but there were no errors belive me - no errors

Comment: I really cannot find any resolution to make it happen.

Comment: I've never user Hyper Terminal so I don't really know what he's doing. The file that he's sending, is it just a plain text file?

Comment: In HyperTerminal (on win XP) you can specify ip, port and choose file to be sent on those ip/port - when i do it printer prints. When i do from code - not

Comment: Looking over this page, your code looks to be fairly spot on (http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_Client_Socket.htm) ... The only thing I might try is to send a little bit of data to the client like this website does (you can see it in the button1.click) to see if it responds. It might actualy be something with the file or the method of the file... this exmple sends just a few bytes of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I've included code to disconnect/close, and dispose the stream and TcpClient.**

With a little modification to your initial code, this sends an entire file (which should work if that's the only thing your label printer requires):

```
Public Sub WriteFile(ByVal FilePath As String, ByRef IP As String)
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Sending file """ & FilePath & """ to " & IP)
        Dim client As New TcpClient()
        client.Connect(IP, 9100)

        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim sendBytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)

        stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

        stream.Close(5000) 'Wait 5 seconds to ensure that the data is sent.
        client.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Example call:

```
WriteFile("C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\Print me.txt", "192.168.1.21")
```

Comment: ok ill check that and let you know what happend - but i see is it not the same code as i showed as last one in my min post? P.S wht is my.setting.commport ? - i replaced that to 9100...

Comment: @JohnDoe : `My.Settings.CommPort` is what you have written in your first code. But I've changed mine to 9100 now.

Comment: Hi Visual - it works !!!! But i have no idea where is the diffrence between your code and mine? WHat exactly is the change? And.. could this code be more let's say secured/tunned as i am going to deploy it on productionwhere we have 15 printers on production.

Comment: @JohnDoe for starters my code reads a file, while your only reads a plan string. The problem could be: **1)** If it's a file that the printer requires it won't know what to do with just a String. **2)** Your choice of encoding (ASCII) could have been unsupported by the printer. **3)** It could have been a problem that you're creating an `IPEndPoint` instead of just entering the IP and port as two parameters.

Comment: And no, I don't think it can be made more secure (if the printer doesn't support something like VPN of course). If you were to encrypt the traffic the printer would not be able to read/print it as normal text.

Comment: Also, it looks to me that Sato's label printers has got a .NET API that works with Visual Basic. See page 8-9: http://www.satoeurope.com/sites/europe/Uploads/Files/Downloads/Integrating_Label_Printing_with_SATO_Label_Gallery.pdf

Comment: Here's a little about their SDK: http://www.satoworldwide.com/sites/satoworldwide_com/Uploads/Files/LabelGallery/ug-LabelGallery_SDK-eng.pdf

Comment: ok ill read about that. Just two more questions: 1) Read the file you mean by using ReadAllBytes its reading file instead string within file - is it not the same? 2) By more secure i ment not encoding/encrypting but code itself - mean maybe is there possible to better close /unrealase file opened or close stream by using..

Comment: @JohnDoe : **1)** It's not the same, no. Because when you're sending a String you're just sending plain text. But when you're sending a file, you're sending something that can immediately be stored somewhere without having to write a new file. And after reading about their SDK you are supposed to use a file for it.

Comment: @JohnDoe : As for your second question, I'm going to edit my answer. You don't need to close or "unrelease" the file, since it's already been closed by `File.ReadAllBytes()`. But you can close the streams and TcpClient. See my edit in a few minutes.

Comment: do you think 5 sec is just enough? What exactly means that 5 sec?

Comment: @JohnDoe : those 5 seconds are just how long the `NetworkStream` will wait before it _actually_ closes itself. You may increase it to 10 sec or something if you need, but it's used to ensure that all data is sent before closing the stream (because if it's closed immediatelly there's a chance that not all data gets sent). See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z5h0h0e(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: As I assume that you're just sending small text files, there is really no need to worry about it as most internet connections today send/receive in speeds of one or more megabytes per second. The 5 second delay is used because **the more** (simultaneous) data you send through the stream, **the less** is the chance that all the data will be sent before closing the stream. But giving the closing of the stream a 5 second (or higher if needed) delay, you'll increase the chance of all data getting sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had to take the file info, save it as a .CLP file (my client's printer is a Zebra thermal label printer) and then my client could print the file that way.

I don't know what format a 'sato' printer uses, but if you can create your text file and save it with that extension, that could work.

Comment: the format is .lbl but what i noticed that's not the matter which is more like what is it inside the file than file extension.